# AngularJS - Provide an array of strings to a child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a product gallery directive in Angular, which will allow the user to scroll through images with left/right arrows.

What is the most appropriate angular approach to feed my directive with the array of image URLs?

You can assume that the parent controller has already made an API call to receive this the array of URLs

E.g.

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyController as myController">
    <my-image-gallery></my-image-gallery>
</div>
```

Should I just have an attribute of  that takes in the JSON array? Perhaps something like:

```
<my-image-gallery images="myController.ImageList"></my-image-gallery>
```

Although, I'm not even sure if the above is possible. It would mean the JSON would have to be converted into a string?

There must be a better way

### Edit

As per comments, I've tried the above method, but I can't access the "images" field from within my controller.

Here is what I have defined in my directive:

```
    scope: {
        imageSource: '='
    },
```

Then in my controller, I assume I should just be able to reference the variable imageSource, shouldn't I?

Comment: if directive is just being used as template it will inherit parent scope if internal scope isn't isolated. `better` is dependent on use case. Your understanding about needing to convert to string is incorrect also

Comment: Thanks. It's not solely used as a template; there will be controller code (left/right arrow buttons) to "scroll" the image. I wanted to isolate the scope of the directive so it doesn't depend on the parent having a certain field. So in this case, would my approach of sending the ImageList array into the directive via an attribute suffice? Or is there a cleaner way? @charlietfl

Comment: sure, just set the scope in directive to match

Comment: Hmmmm... So I'm using the approach described above. How do I access the "images" object from within my controller code then? I've tried self.images and $scope.images, and none of them work. @charlietfl. I'll update my question to reflect this

Comment: It does not need to be converted in to a string. The attribute can take the object (array) directly. Just try it before asking. You can't break anything. If it doesn't work then come back.

Comment: Thanks @Lenny. I've tried this method (see recent edit) yet I can't seem to access the variable from within my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using a kinda weird tutorial or something to learn angular. You can use the `MyController as MyController` syntax, but the goal of that is to avoid using `$scope`. I personally don't agree with it and don't understand why people would want to do that.

When you attach a value to `$scope` it becomes available in your view directly (without needing `$scope`). For example, `$scope.images` would be passed in to your directive as just `images`.

To have the directive process that value as a variable instead of a string it must be defined using an `=` (as opposed to an `@`) you can read more about this in the [angular directive docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Here is an example of how this would work:

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

  $scope.imageList=['img1','img2','img3','img...'];

}])

.directive('myImageGallery',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      images:'='
    },
    controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
      console.log($scope.images);
    }],
    replace: true,
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="img in images">{{img}}</li></ul>'
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <my-image-gallery images="imageList"></my-image-gallery>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and here is a [plunker of it in action](http://embed.plnkr.co/txgldMqeah5elMnB50ef/preview).

Comment: Thanks @Lenny! So is there any way to do this without $scope?

Comment: Yes, you can do `myCtrl as myCtrl` and then `myCtrl.imageList` and in the controller instead of `$scope.imageList` you do `this.imageList`, but again... I really don't know why anyone would want to avoid `$scope` it is a core part of angular and it works great. When you avoid it you have to do a bunch of hacks / workarounds to make basic things like watchers work correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Lenny. One more question: Is there a way to perform some action when imageList is loaded? For example, I have a line `ng-src="{{ currentImage }}` in my code. So when imageList is successfully loaded, I want to set `currentImage = imageList[0]`. Is there a callback function to achieve this?

Comment: You could just do it in the first line of the controller (inside the directive). OR if you think the data could be changed later you could use a watcher. a `$watch` function can be attached to any `$scope` value and it will trigger whenever the value of that variable is changed. Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch